# AVAudiosession deprecated issue

Tags: ios

How to destroy or close audio session within my application in iOS.

I added some code but it throw waring(set delegate is deprecated)

```
     AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
     [audioSession setDelegate:nil];
```

HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the method:

```
- (BOOL)setActive:(BOOL)beActive error:(NSError **)outError
```

to activate or deactivate your AVAudioSession. This will close the session.
If you need delegates for warning other classes you may use notifications.

Hope it helps!